# Rails: Passing controller variable to JS using ERB slows page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There are two ways I know of to pass variables defined in a controller (/action) to JS...

## The official way is

**.js.erb**:

```
var banana = "<% @banana %>"
```

## *Another* way (that I'm currently using is)

**.html.erb**

```
<span id="banana-variable" style="display:none"><% @banana %></span>
```

**.js**

```
var banana = $("#banana-variable").html()
```

This js file is loaded on multiple actions/views across the controller. It makes sense to me to not use a .erb extension: users cache it the first time they hit any action/view in the controller. They then won't have to download different versions of the file when they browse to different pages. Am I right?

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: `var banana = "<% @banana %>"`  pass nothing. `<span id="banana-variable" style="display:none"><% @banana %></span>`  pass nothing too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, are right. The javascript will be cached on the client's browser.

Still you want to send data on the 'js' or script files you can use this gem called [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon).

Answer (score 2):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

I recommend you use gem 'gon', which is thoroughly introduced in RailsCast. It makes your controller cleaner. Your method will make it more troublesome if you're trying to pass an array or hash to js.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are using `<% %>` which will execute the code, instead of `<%= %>` which will execute the code and *render* the result back into the template.

Comment: The javascript file is downloaded by the client when they hit a different action, so how are they going to load either of those at that point?

Answer (score 0):

With [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) you can access the page only after the html page is loaded. From what I understand it uses web page as a proxy to transfer data from rails server to javascript.
But if you want to use the variable at any point of time you want, you can do an ajax(post) request from javascript to the rails controller and retrieve the value as json.

**Example:**

**AJAX Request:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <PageURL>,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
          data = JSON.parse(data);
        },
      });
```

your "data" will contain the returned value.

On the controller side it should be:

**Controller:**

```
def <PageURL>
    render :json => {:result => <value_you_want_to_return>}
end
```

Do not forget to define the controller's path in **routes.rb** file.